# How do you include romainguy's ViewServer in Android Studio with Gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to use RomainGuy's ViewServer (https://github.com/romainguy/ViewServer) with my Android Studio project using Gradle, and I can't get it to work.

My understanding is to add a folder in project root ('libraries'), drop the ViewServer directory into it (not the full `ViewServer` directory but the actual library `viewserver` folder within `ViewServer`, and reference it in settings.gradle

```
include ':VendorSearch'
include ':libraries:ViewServer'
```

and also in my build.gradle file

```
compile project(":libraries:ViewServer")
```

When I do this I get a message that says

```
Could not find any version that matches com.android.tools.build.gradle:0.5.+
```

I tried then manually updating build.gradle in ViewServer to use the latest build tools (0.7.+ at the time of posting), but I get the same error with the new gradle version.

Any help and general clarification of how to include non-jar third party libraries would be appreciated!

Comment: Check this link http://www.androidsx.com/how-to-link-an-android-library-project-with-gradle-in-android-studio/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to add the repository. Change the `gradle.build` from:

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 18
  buildToolsVersion '18.0.1'
}
```

to

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 18
  buildToolsVersion '18.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I also needed to move the `compileSdkVersion` to 19 and `buildToolsVersion` to 19.0.1

Comment: @loeschg In the same build script change the compileSdkVersion to 19 and buildToolsVersion '19.0.1'. Make sure to clean your project ./gradlew clean